# PHP Comment system using File Writer

Tags: php, html, css, file

I found a code from my old projects and I want to use it in my new project. But its not really working.
Its a comment system with file writer and reader functions. I want to make a question system but if I write into the input field and submit it, nothing happen. The txt file is empty. Any idea why?

Code:

```
//Write into the file
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    $com  = $_POST[ "askQuestion" ];
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "a" );
    fwrite( $file, "<font color=\"#84bd00\"><em>Anonymous:</em></font><font color=\"#8D929C\"> " );
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $com ) - 1; $i++ ) {
        fwrite( $file, $com[ $i ] );
        if ( $i % 37 == 0 && $i != 0 ) fwrite( $file);
    }          
    fwrite( $file, "<br></font>" );
    fwrite( $file, "<em><font size=\"2px\" color=\"#aaa\">Sent: ".date('Y F j, H:i:s')."</font></em>");
    fwrite( $file, "<hr>"); 
    fclose( $file );
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>';
}
?>

//Read the txt file
<?php
if (file_exists("inrg.txt")) {
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "r" );
    echo fread( $file, filesize( "inrg.txt" ) );
    fclose( $file );
}
?>

<textarea type="text" name="askQuestion" id="askQuestion" class="askField" rows="10" cols="50" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Review" class="reviewBtn" />
```

Comment: When you check the contents of `$_POST` while debugging, do you have a field called "submit"?

Comment: Only the last row have the submit.

Comment: If it does not work, rewrite it for the new project

Comment: Specially as `<font>`  [`is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Comment: You should not use files as a database.

Comment: I created a new folder with a index.php and the .txt file and it works fine. But I don't know why it can't work with the wanted index.php file.

Comment: Create a file with this name (inrg.txt) put it in same folder it will work.

Comment: I tried to create the inrg.txt and also I gave it chmod 777 too

Comment: @ArSeN tell that to the people at SQLite...

Comment: Well there might be exceptions to that rule ;) However I'd not recommend SQLite for a production setup either.